# How could you generate an APK from project B programmatically, using a button click from project A?

Tags: android

I have a project A that should use a wizard to create a project B. Project B is based on a template. Project A should send data to that template and generate an APK from this data and template programmatically.

I've read about the APK structure and what it includes, like classes, resources, and manifest files. My question is, what is the best way to achieve this template-based generation of an APK? What could I use for this?

Comment: This question is huge and not a good fit for StackOverflow.  You would have to write (or find third party libraries for) a Java compiler, a DVM compiler, the assets packager etc.  Effectively writing most of the Android ADT.  The APK is just a zip file.  It's the contents that are the problem.

Comment: Don't you guys look at the answers before closing a question? I was able to find him an open source solution that does everything Simon mentions. It's an incredible project, but it's there -- it exists.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk - yes, though there's actually nothing in the question that says it is supposed to be done on the device.  It could be as simple as a script to copy and do some global renaming, resulting in a project ready for use with the normal android dev tools.

Comment: Chris, that's very true. May be, I answered the wrong question. Reading comprehension may not be my strong point either.

Answer (score 0):

This is the open source project you're looking for.

https://code.google.com/p/terminal-ide/

> Terminal IDE is a command line java / android dev kit that runs on the device itself. Using a correctly configured vim, bash and busybox, in a custom terminal + custom keyboard environment. All these applications are put together so that they interact correctly. A full Terminal emulator + custom ANSI keyboard ensure good bash, vim and busybox emulation. All set up and ready to run in a NON-ROOT environment. Normal user permissions are enough to run all of this.

You can also download it from Google Play [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&hl=en). The application has 4.7 stars on the Play Store from 1,324 ratings. Here is one of the latest written 5 stars reviews this application received on Google Play. And it's not unique by any means (the emphasis in **bold** is mine).

> A Google User - March 12, 2013 - Version 2.02
>    Wow!
>
> I have over 30 years programming experience (mostly in C/C++ and Assembly) and have been looking to learn to program Android. **I looked everywhere for a way to compile and run Java tutorials on my tablet, with no success, until I found Terminal IDE!** Then I started playing around with its capabilities and let me say again, wow. DEVELOPER - I have only one suggestion, which others have brought up too: reduce the internal memory footprint. Maybe breakup the different languages into installable add-ons?

In a way, it's a lot like the Android Java IDE called AIDE, minus the GUI interface (but unlike AIDE, it's doesn't have low artificial file limits, and since it's open source it can actually be used to build your own project upon and extend).